# How to optimize images in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, image, optimization, slow-response

My site speed is very slow. Can anyone please let me know how can I optimize all the images? So, my site loading can be faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points regarding your question:

- Image optimization

If you want to optimize your images, you could use this module: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_Webp2/

It works pretty well for images that use Magento media libraries to be created. On the other hand, if you're using images directly in your CMS/Block pages, you should optimize your images before uploading them. You can use https://tiny-img.com/webp/ or any other online converters.

- Site speed

This is tricky. It isn't only images that can slow down your site, there are many factors to take into account. To improve the site speed you need to check:

** Extensions you have installed
** Custom developments
** Magento Theme you're using
** Server configuration
** Deployment mode

You can check this post in Mageplaza: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/speed-up-magento-2.html

Usually this won't be enough, but it's a good point to start from.

Answer (score 0):

For image optimize
you can try this one https://github.com/haihv433/Magento2ImageOptimizer
add this to crontab will save the day